# Aggregate all customers matching a criteria and filter by a column value

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, powerpivot

In a list of customers, by a selected period I need to:

- Determine if a customer is new, no longer a customer, or bought more/less than PY
- Aggregate those categorizations and sum the YOY change for each category by period, and provide a count of customers for each categorization

Additionally, I have 6+ dimensions (BU, Type, Portfolio, etc) that could be used to filter the data, and no matter if there are 0, 1, 6 or any combination, need to aggregate the customer data by category.

**What I've tried:**

Measure to detemine the customer categorization. I can put this into a pivot and it correctly returns the category by customer regardless of the dimensions and filters.

```
Churn Cat :=
IF (
    AND ( [TTM Beginning ARR] = 0, [TTM Ending ARR] > 0 ),
    "New",
    IF (
        [TTM Ending ARR] > [TTM Beginning ARR],
        "Upsell",
        IF (
            AND ( [TTM Beginning ARR] > 0, [TTM Ending ARR] = 0 ),
            "Term",
            IF (
                [TTM Beginning ARR] > [TTM Ending ARR],
                "Down",
                IF ( 
                    [TTM Beginning ARR] = [TTM Ending ARR], 
                    "No Change", 
                    "Other" 
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Measure: Beginning Revenue Trailing 12 Months. This works

```
TTM Ending Revenue :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( data_All[Amount] ),
    DATESBETWEEN ( 'Calendar'[Date], [CY Start Date], [CY End Date] )
)
```

Measure: Ending Revenue Trailing 12 Months. This works

```
TTM Beginning Revenue :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( data_All[Amount] ),
    DATESBETWEEN ( 'Calendar'[Date], [PY Start Date], [PY End Date] )
)
```

Measure: YoY Change. This works

```
YOY Change:=[TTM Ending Revenue]-[TTM Beginning Revenue]
```

**What I would do if I was working in Excel:**

Create a pivot with the Churn Cat and YoY Calculations. Then do a sumif to total all the YOY changes for New, Upsell, Term, Down. This pivot would allow me to filter on the various dimensions and the calculations would remain the same.

I'm fairly new to Data Warehouse calculations and unsure how to approach recreating the excel/pivot approach in PowerBI or PowerPivot DAX calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I think your [Churn Cat] measure should be a calculated column instead of being a measure. (Cause later It will be used for grouping data together with BU. DWH concepts here!)

After making this, A measure like this will solve your problem, I think:

```
Final_Measure =
VAR Summary_BU_Category =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, YourTable[BU], YourTable[Churn Cat] ),
        "YOY Change", [Year over Year change] -- [YOY] is your defined measure here!
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( Summary_BU_Category, [YOY Change] )
```

Then you can use it , sliced by BU and Category!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure I've explained well enough. I need to attempt again at my description.

Comment: I think @OzanSen is correct here - it seems like you want to add a categorization for your matrix to use as row-based or columnar information. For this you would absolutely need to persist a column in your data model, either thru a DAX calculated column or a computed column in Power Query (or, ideally, straight from the database query).

Comment: An additional thought: It also looks like you need to do this dynamically - and honestly, solving a use-case that advanced is something I would only do if I was paid :-) As a starting point, I would look at the `Dynamic ABC Classification` section in this article by SQLBI: https://www.daxpatterns.com/abc-classification/ The hint is that the categorization does need to be persisted into the model somehow, but you can dynamically assign elements to the given categories in a rule-based model. With your rules, it is not an easy job.

Comment: @Marcus Thanks for the response. And fair point on the paid comment. I'm learning how complex this request is. I'll dig in on the ABC Classification link.